# Why was Chell selected for Voyager's Hazard Team?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, video-games, star-trek-eu

The Bolian named [**Chell**](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Chell) was a Maquis engineer who got sucked to the Delta Quadrant along with his crewmates and ended up on Voyager. He was generally portrayed as loud-mouthed, rude, and lazy. He was one of the five candidates for Tuvok's disciplinary program in episode S1E16 "Learning Curve", and still hadn't completely accepted his role in Starfleet by episode S7E04 "Repression", which takes place six years later. In general, Chell was considered by many to be the epitome of what a Starfleet crewman should NOT be.

Yet, when Tuvok began accepting applications for the new [Hazard Team](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager_-_Elite_Force) in 2376 (a full year before "Repression"), Chell applied and was accepted with a promotion to Ensign. The Hazard Team was designed to be an elite response unit which could easily be responsible for the lives of everyone onboard the ship.

**Given this crewman's past & overall attitude, what possible reasons would Tuvok have had to accept Chell as a Hazard Team member, let alone with a promotion?**

Comment: Tongue in cheek: Someone might count on a competent hazard dealing with the incompetent crewman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [Voyager : Elite Force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager_%E2%80%93_Elite_Force) (and its sequel Elite Force II) weren't part of the official Star Trek canon. That being the case, the writers of the TV show weren't beholden to the events therein.

For [VOY: Repression](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/704.htm) it made good sense to return some Maquis characters that avid TV viewers would remember, but it presumably made less sense to have them relating to events that only occurred in a PC game that relatively few of their viewers would have heard of, let alone played.

---

As to why ***in the Elite Force game***, Chell was chosen to become a member of the team, the short answer is that he was a competent technician and because he was persuaded to apply by Munro, with whom he had become friends over the intervening years. There also appear to be a dearth of qualified applicants, which Tuvok notes (and bemoans) during the training sequence.

Chell acquits himself reasonably well over the events of the game and demonstrates a high level of skill and even a certain amount of aggression when needed, despite his apparent pacifism in the TV show.